# ADF - Airflow Managed Instance - How to share files(mount files) from airflow worker to kubernetespodoperator

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have created and setup an Airflow integration runtime environment(using ADF - Managed Airflow). Then I imported DAGs and other dependencies from azure blob storage into the Airflow environment(Managed Airflow) using linked service.

I have a task of running a shell script which has kubectl commands. Hence, I thought the below operator would help.

```
submit_spark_app_task1 = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id="submit_spark_app_task1",
    name="kubectl-submit-spark-app",
    namespace="spark-apps",
    image="bitnami/kubectl:latest",
    cmds=["sh", "-c", "./sparkapplication_spark-pi.sh "],
    service_account_name="airflow-sparkapp",
      trigger_rule="all_success",
    get_logs=True,
    kubernetes_conn_id="k8s-airflow",
    dag=dag
)
```

But, it resulted in error:

```
[2024-01-10, 11:57:51 UTC] {pod_manager.py:381} INFO - sh: 0: cannot open c: No such file
```

The above error occurred as the pod couldn't find the script: sparkapplication_spark-pi.sh.

Then, I executed BashOperator to see the dags location in airflow worker.

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime

test_dag = DAG('bash_operator_demo', schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1), start_date=datetime(2023, 2, 15))

bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash_task',
    bash_command='ls -lrta /opt/airflow/dags',
    dag=test_dag
)
```

output of the above:

> [2024-01-10, 17:46:45 UTC] {task_command.py:410} INFO - Running
> <TaskInstance: test_bash_dag.bash_task
> manual__2024-01-10T17:46:42.861832+00:00 [running]> on host
> af-722224f4-418e-49d1-84e4-2f62a00eae82-worker-0.af-722224f4-418e-49d1-84e4-2f62a00eae82-worker.adf.svc.cluster.local [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1545} INFO - Exporting env
> vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='airflow'
> AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='test_bash_dag' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='bash_task'
> AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2024-01-10T17:46:42.861832+00:00'
> AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1'
> AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2024-01-10T17:46:42.861832+00:00'
> [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:63} INFO - Tmp dir root
> location: /tmp [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:75} INFO -
> Running command: ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'ls -lrta /opt/airflow/dags']
> [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:86} INFO - Output:
> [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - total 27
> [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - drwxrwxrwx 2
> 1000 1000    0 Jan  4 04:15 . [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC]
> {subprocess.py:93} INFO - drwxrwxr-x 1 airflow root 4096 Jan  4 04:17
> .. [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - drwxrwxrwx 2
> 1000 1000    0 Jan  4 11:21 **pycache** [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC]
> {subprocess.py:93} INFO - -rwxrwxrwx 1    1000 1000  375 Jan 10 17:46
> BashOperator-demo.py [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:93}
> INFO - -rwxrwxrwx 1    1000 1000 1622 Jan 10 17:46 dag2.py
> [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - -rwxrwxrwx 1
> 1000 1000 3232 Jan 10 17:46 delete-spark-app.py [2024-01-10, 17:46:47
> UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - -rwxrwxrwx 1    1000 1000 2142 Jan 10
> 17:46 hello-world-spark-app-history-shilton-image.yml [2024-01-10,
> 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - -rwxrwxrwx 1    1000 1000  853
> Jan 10 17:46 new-spark-pi.yaml [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC]
> {subprocess.py:93} INFO - -rwxrwxrwx 1    1000 1000 2932 Jan 10 17:46
> sample-dag.py [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO -
> -rwxrwxrwx 1    1000 1000 1119 Jan 10 17:46 spark-pi3.yml [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - -rwxrwxrwx 1    1000 1000 1119
> Jan 10 17:46 spark-pi4.yml [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC]
> {subprocess.py:93} INFO - -rwxrwxrwx 1    1000 1000  764 Jan 10 17:46
> sparkapplication_spark-pi.sh [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC]
> {subprocess.py:93} INFO - -rwxrwxrwx 1    1000 1000 2058 Jan 10 17:46
> submit-spark-app.py [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:97} INFO
>
> - Command exited with return code 0 [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1345} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.
>   dag_id=test_bash_dag, task_id=bash_task,
>   execution_date=20240110T174642, start_date=20240110T174644,
>   end_date=20240110T174647 [2024-01-10, 17:46:47 UTC]
>   {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
>   [2024-01-10, 17:46:48 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2653} INFO - 0 downstream
>   tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check

You can see that the file: sparkapplication_spark-pi.sh and other dags are in the airflow worker. However, I want the files in the airflow worker(/opt/airflow/dags) to be shared with kubernetespodoperator's pod.

How is that possible?

Note: I don't want to use PVC/Config-map